# Jupyter Notebook not including THREE.js

Tags: javascript, html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have the following jupyter notebook cell, with fourd.js and r89dev.three.min.js in a js folder in the same directory as the notebook:

```
%%html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FourD.js Testbed</title>
        <script src="js/r89dev.three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/fourd.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="display"></div>
        <script>
var CIRCLES = 100;
var CIRCLE_SIZE = 10;

fourd = new FourD();
fourd.init('#display', {width: 500, height: 350});
fourd._internals.camera.position.set(0, 0, -50);
var vertex1 = fourd.graph.add_vertex({size: 10, color: 0x000000});
var vertex2 = fourd.graph.add_vertex({size: 10, color: 0x000000});
var edge = fourd.graph.add_edge(vertex1, vertex2);

for(var i=0; i<CIRCLES; i++){
    vertex_options = [];
    for(var j=0; j<CIRCLE_SIZE; j++){
        vertex_options.push({size: 10, color: 0x000000});
    }

    fourd.graph.add_cycle(vertex_options);
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It worked the first time I tried it, but now I get an error that THREE is not defined. That means it's loading the fourd.js library, just not the three.js library. What could I be missing?

The error I get directly in the notebook is the following:

```
Javascript error adding output!
ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

but I can't find a corresponding error message about three js not loading in the javascript console.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: remove the `// three.js - http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js` comment from the beginning of `xxx.three.min.js`

I can not tell where it goes wrong, but you are seeing an interference between JavaScript [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) prologue and comments.

If you try the following cell:

```
%%html
<div id="log"></div>
<script>
/* set a to a */
var a="a";$("#log").append("a is set to "+a+"<br>");
try{asdfg=1;}catch(x){$("#log").append(x+"<br>");}
</script>
<script>
"use strict";
/* set b to b */
var b="b";$("#log").append("b is set to "+b+"<br>");
try{bsdfg=1;}catch(x){$("#log").append(x+"<br>");}
</script>
<script>
/* set c to c */
"use strict";
var c="c";$("#log").append("c is set to "+c+"<br>");
try{csdfg=1;}catch(x){$("#log").append(x+"<br>");}
</script>
<script>
$("#log").append("Checking things:<br>");
try{$("#log").append("a is "+a+"<br>");}catch(x){$("#log").append("a is nope: "+x+"<br>");}
try{$("#log").append("b is "+b+"<br>");}catch(x){$("#log").append("b is nope: "+x+"<br>");}
try{$("#log").append("c is "+c+"<br>");}catch(x){$("#log").append("c is nope: "+x+"<br>");}
</script>
```

, it produces the following output (tested with Chrome, Firefox and IE):

> ```
> a is set to a
> b is set to b
> ReferenceError: bsdfg is not defined
> c is set to c
> ReferenceError: csdfg is not defined
> Checking things:
> a is a
> b is b
> c is nope: ReferenceError: c is not defined
> ```

Where the "x set to x" messages show that all a-b-c blocks run fine, the two ReferenceErrors in the middle show that both b and c are running in strict mode, which is also expected.
The unexpected thing is that `c` is not set at the end, producing the third ReferenceError.

I can not explain how the comments matter for Jupyter, but they do. `three.min.js` starts with a comment line, and then it behaves like `c`, remaining undefined. `fourd.js` starts with `"use strict";`, and the starting comment comes only after that, and it works.

It seems to be a Jupyter-only thing, as the following snippet works fine even when embedded here:

```html
<script>
    /* set a to a */
    var a="a";
    console.log("a is set to "+a);
    try{asdfg=1;}catch(x){console.log(x);}
</script>
<script>
    "use strict";
    /* set b to b */
    var b="b";
    console.log("b is set to "+b);
    try{bsdfg=1;}catch(x){console.log(x);}
</script>
<script>
    /* set c to c */
    "use strict";
    var c="c";
    console.log("c is set to "+c);
    try{csdfg=1;}catch(x){console.log(x);}
</script>
<script>
    try{console.log(a);}catch(x){console.log(x);}
    try{console.log(b);}catch(x){console.log(x);}
    try{console.log(c);}catch(x){console.log(x);}
</script>
```

(The two expected ReferenceError-s show up as empty `{}`-s, but they are there, and all a-b-c are set properly at the end)

Comment: BTW, if someone without a Jupyter installation wants to try, https://jupyter.org/try is a place for that. Start the Python one, press the ```[+]``` button to add a cell, paste the content, and use Ctrl+Enter to evaluate it.